# Can "Web Setup Project" (Visual Studio) restrict choices for "Application Pool"?

Tags: application-pool, web-setup-project

Can "Web Setup Project" (Visual Studio) restrict choices for "Application Pool"?

I am moving a project from .NET 2+ to .NET 4+.  I use the (VS 2010) project type "Setup and Deployment, Visual Studio Installer".  On the "Select Installation Address" Form, "Application Pool" offers a drop-down of all available IIS application pools.

This was OK previously, because my application could run under .NET 2 or .NET 4.  However, now that I am compiling for .NET 4, I need end-users to install to a .NET 4 application pool.  I had expected the installer to detect this and only offer .NET 4+ pools, but it does not (btw, "ASPNETVersion" property setting does not alter this); it does not even default to one; and choices do not indicate what .NET version they are.  My end-users do not understand all of this.

I do not want to get rid of standard dialogs --- the only change I want is in what is offered for application pools.  And I do not want to change installer development project type.

Is there anywhere to influence what choices are at runtime (would need to be by Framework version, I cannot know what end-user pools might be named)?  I am surprised no one else seems to have asked this as it's a pretty obvious requirement for end-users.

Comment: Since nobody has answered, I'll say I have found that I can at least cause the drop-down box to select a desired pool by passing `TARGETAPPPOOL="..."` on the command-line (I have a "wrapper" setup which invokes the **.msi**).  But there seems to be no way to influence the list choices (which are generated by an internal call to `GatherAppPools()`)...